# Change option text in select tag just with CSS

Tags: css, select

I have a select tag and I don't have access to edit that .

Now how can I edit option text ?

For example :

```
<select>
   <option id="1">text 1</option>
   <option id="2">text 2</option>
   <option id="3">text 3</option>
</select>
```

Change to :

```
<select>
   <option id="1">text 1</option>
   <option id="2">text 8</option>
   <option id="3">text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery or plain JavaScript to modify the content, but still you have to add JS code into the file.

Comment: @Raptor thanks . Can you help me that how can I create this jquery or javascript code ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to include jQuery in your HTML. Then, add this JS in your HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=sel_test] option[id=2]').text('text 8');
});
```

Live Demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enuf7dvb/)